# Is there any command line query that I can use for VLC to automatically load a video at a specified time?

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player

I just want to know a command line script that can you know have parameters that you can just put into the script so that VLC just loads up ans start the video from that point on.
Also, if there's a way to make it stop at a pre-defined point in the video.
Also, is there any way to make it stop dynamically...like you know before the last 20 seconds of a show, so that I may ignore the credits at the end of the video..
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: The operating system that I'm trying on is Windows 7, however, because i'm trying for a Command line argument, those should be the same I guess in other OSs as well!

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SuperUser.

Unfortunately the `--start-time=<x>` and `--stop-time=<x>` option has been broken since VLC version 0.9.0.  It might still be worth a try though.

You can read about it on their forums: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=59699

Here are the available options.

```
 --start-time=<float>       Start time
      The stream will start at this position (in seconds).
  --stop-time=<float>        Stop time
      The stream will stop at this position (in seconds).
  --run-time=<float>         Run time
      The stream will run this duration (in seconds).
```